# xmlrpc newPaste - expected an object with the buffer interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, xmlrpclib

in py2 there was

```
rv = xmlrpc.pastes.newPaste(language, code, None, filename, mimetype, private)
```

I'm getting error : expected an object with the buffer interface

Can't find any docs about xmlrpc and py3. I found only this snippet :

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['gpg','--clearsign'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdin.write(bytes(input, 'UTF8'))
output = p1.communicate()[0]

s = ServerProxy('http://paste.pocoo.org/xmlrpc/')
pasteid = s.pastes.newPaste('text',output.decode())
print ("http://paste.pocoo.org/raw/",pasteid,"/", sep="")
```

but I'm still being confused about it... my version used many arguments, where can I find full description of it / fix for it ?

Thank you.

Comment: The arguments are the same as you're already using. You just have to make sure that text is `str`, not `bytes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message usually means it's looking for `str` (which is Unicode in Python 3), not `bytes` . Like in the example, you'll need to decode the argument which is in bytes. Maybe:

```
rv = xmlrpc.pastes.newPaste(language, code.decode(), None, filename, mimetype, private)
```

But it's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing your code.

Comment: there are only None and private non-str elements

Comment: @nCdy: Can you replicate it with some non-private examples? Because that error is exactly what I see if `code` is bytes instead of str.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3. `xmlrpclib` has been split into two modules, `xmlrpc.client` and `xmlrpc.server`.

The docs for 3.2.1 can be found at:

http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/library/xmlrpc.client.html

http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/library/xmlrpc.server.html

Comment: The snippet in the question is very much to do with xmlrpc. That's where the ServerProxy class comes from.

Comment: Well, it kind of does help. `output.decode()` is the sort of thing that he'll need to use to correct that error.

Comment: Still have no idea how to fix my trouble, but thank you for docs.

Comment: @Thomas is right, nCdy, `str` has changed in Python3 to `bytes`, and the 'string' type is `unicode`. You should try `.decode()` on any strings (which are actually `bytes`) you're passing, so that they get turned into `unicode`.